# Flutter ios does not scroll properly to the end

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, mobile, mobile-development

I have some scrolls in my app and they work perfectly in the android but in the ios they don't work properly when they are scrolled to the end.

[image]

it should be like this:

[image]

screen code:
the 85 bottom padding is for bottom navigation.

```
ListView.separated(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                            bottom: constraints.maxHeight > (size.height - 70)
                                ? 85
                                : 0),
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          ListModel list = bookProvider.lists[index];
                          return HorizontalList(
                            list: list,
                            itemOnTap: (index) => Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => BookDetailsScreen(
                                      book: list.books[index]),
                                )),
                          );
```

Comment: Did you add [`Scaffold`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold-class.html)?

Comment: Please add some code to support your question

Comment: @WakemeUpNow Its parent has

Comment: @Davis added some code

Answer (score 0):

Try to add physics in Listview as below

```
ListView.separated(
           physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(), // <-- Add this
               padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  bottom: constraints.maxHeight > (size.height - 70)
                        ? 85
                        : 0),
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      ListModel list = bookProvider.lists[index];
                      return HorizontalList(
                        list: list,
                        itemOnTap: (index) => Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => BookDetailsScreen(
                                  book: list.books[index]),
                            )),
                      );
```

Comment: didn't work I don't know what wrong with it, it work on android but not on ios